# Git add with a submodule path instead adds all the files in the submodule

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

So, I've recently added a new submodule to an existing project, but it appears something has gone wrong with the installation. Firstly any attempt to `git add` that directory adds all the files beneath it, but not the folder itself, not great.

Signs that it's installed as a submodule:

It's in .gitmodules

```
[submodule "vendor/plugins/redacted_chemistry"]
    path = vendor/plugins/redacted_chemistry
    url = git@github.com:biorails/redacted_chemistry.git
    branch = develop_5.3
```

It's got an entry in .git/modules/vendor/plugins/

Signs it's not working as expected:

- `git add vendor/plugins/redacted_chemistry` adds all of the files within that folder to the parent repository. (not the submodule pointer)
- `git submodule foreach ...` doesn't include that directory.

Why isn't git treating this submodule the same way as the others?

Comment: It seems you execute `git submodule add git@github.com:biorails/redacted_chemistry.git` at `root/vendor/plugins` directory, then the `vendor/plugins/redacted_chemistry` and `.gitmodules` will be staged automatically. You just need to use `git commit` (not `git add`), and you will find the mode of `vendor/plugins/redacted_chemistry` is 160000 (committed as submodule).